# How to separate two domains with a single analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have accidentally set up the same analytics account for two domains of the same website.
Once discovered,  i have seperated them to two different accounts, but i need to pull out / see the data for the new domain from the old account.

Is there any way to do that? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once data has been inserted into a Google Analytics account it can not be changed.   Nor can it be moved to another account or property.

You will have to analyze the old data where it is or you could apply a filter to the data to separate the old from the new how ever this may remove permanently some of the data.

Answer (score 0):

As DaImTo writes, you cannot move or change data in Google Analytics once it has been processed, nor switch its properties or accounts.

To best accomodate when an error like you describe happen, try appending a Hostname-filter to a secondary dimension in the report you are looking at. Or, better yet, segment your data with Hostname as your Dimension and add the different Hostnames as your segment.

Then you can parse through your data independently of each domain.